# What is appropriate video structured data when using HLS or Dash?

Tags: seo, schema.org, rich-snippets, video, streaming

This is an example of standard [structured data for video by Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/video):

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "VideoObject",
  "name": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "thumbnailUrl": "...",
  "uploadDate": "2016-03-31T08:00:00+08:00",
  "duration": "PT1M54S",
  "contentUrl": "https://www.example.com/video/123/file.mp4",
  "embedUrl": "https://www.example.com/embed/123",
  "interactionCount": "5647018"
}
```

Here, there is the `contentUrl` field which points to an MP4 file.

**What should I use for `contentUrl` because I'm using Dash and there is no single MP4 file?**

I insist about this because I think it's playing the main role when Google decides to show the rich snippets of video in the search result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already going through the trouble of using Dash, you may consider having an extra copy of the video as a single MP4 file both for the purposes of this structured data and also as a fallback for legacy browsers.

However if you would rather not do that, realize that `contentUrl` is just a recommended property and not a required property. Not just YouTube (which you would expect to have an in with Google Search), but also other third party video sites like Vimeo leave out the `contentUrl` property for their videos and they still get rich snippets, so it's not strictly required at least if your site has a certain amount of authority.